# Terminal: How to display vertical overflow in split view side-by-side

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, overflow, terminal-emulator, horizontal-scaling

As it's quite exhausting to look at an ultra tall monitor (rotated ultrawide monitor) just to display long vertical output on a single screen,
I am wondering if there's a tiny program that could be fed the output of an arbitrary command via pipe and display vertical overflow on the right half of the terminal (while halfing the available terminal width reported to the program before the pipe).

So that

```
 ___________________
[AAA                ]
[BBB                ]
[CCC                ]
 ^ultrawide-monitor^
     ___|   |___
 DDD  <- vertical
 EEE     overflow 
 FFF
```

becomes

```
 ___________________
[AAA        DDD     ]
[BBB        EEE     ]
[CCC        FFF     ]
 ^ultrawide-monitor^
     ___|   |___
```

Comment: exactly what I am looking for, did you find anything?